# What does is mean by differentiate a matrix $E - DB^{-1}C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-topology

The problem I am trying to solve is:

> Prove that the set of $m \times n$ is matrices of rank $r$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{mn}$ of of codimension $(m - r)(n -r)$. [HINT: Suppose, for simplicity, that an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ has the form 
>   $$A = \begin{pmatrix} B & C \\ D & E \end{pmatrix},$$
>   where the $r \times r$ matrix $B$ is nonsingular, $C$ is $r$ row $n-r$ column, $D$ is $m-r$ row, $r$ column, and $E$ is $m-r$ row, $n-r$ column. Postmultiply by the nonsin-gular matrix 
>   $$\begin{pmatrix} I & -B^{-1}C\\ 0 & I \end{pmatrix}$$
>   to prove that rank$(A)= r$ if and only if $E - DB^{-1}C = 0$.]

In order to show $U \cap M$ is a submanifold of $U$ of codimension $(m-r)(n-r)$, it suffices to show that 0 is a regular value of $E - DB^{-1}C$. That is to show that every $(m-r)(n-r)$ matrix $F$ is in the image of the derivative of $E - DB^{-1}C$, But,

**But what does is mean by differentiate $E - DB^{-1}C$? Particularly, how to differentiate it in the direction
$$\mathfrak{F} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0  \\ 0 & F \end{pmatrix}?$$**

I tried according to definition:
\begin{eqnarray*}
d(E - DB^{-1}C)_\mathfrak{F}(X) & = &\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(E - DB^{-1}C)(\mathfrak{F} + tX) - (E - DB^{-1}C)(\mathfrak{F})}{t}\\
\text{By linearity:}& = & \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(E - DB^{-1}C)(\mathfrak{F}) + t(E - DB^{-1}C)(X) - (E - DB^{-1}C)(\mathfrak{F})}{t}\\
& = & (E - DB^{-1}C)(X)\\
\end{eqnarray*}

So I got the derivative of $E - DB^{-1}C$ at the direction of $F$ is $E - DB^{-1}C$, how can I draw the conclusion that it is surjective? As a matter of fact, I don't even sure if it is a good idea to differentiate in the $\mathfrak{F}$ direction, since $E - DB^{-1}C$ is $m-r$ row, $n-r$ column matrix.

This disagrees with other people's work, whose derivative results $F$ rather than identity.

Thanks

Comment: What is «the dervative of an $m\times n$ matrix»? Derivative with respect to what? I honestly cannot tell what you are talking about in this question.

Comment: (You have asked many questions already on this site... At this point, it would be nice if you had already caught up with the fact that putting a little bit more of work in your questions is desirable! :-( )

Comment: oh sorry @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez , give me a few minutes to improve it.